# Opposite of XMMatrixDecompose() in DirectX math?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, game-engine

I am using the function

```c
bool XM_CALLCONV XMMatrixDecompose(
  XMVECTOR  *outScale,
  XMVECTOR  *outRotQuat,
  XMVECTOR  *outTrans,
  FXMMATRIX M
);
```

To break up a view matrix so I can modify it with keyboard and mouse movements,

```c
XMVECTOR out_scale, out_rot_quat, out_trans;
XMMatrixDecompose(&out_scale, &out_rot_quat, &out_trans, view_matrix);
```

I need to then compose the view matrix using modified `out_scale, out_rot_quat, out_trans`

What is the equivalent DirectXMath function to do this? 
There is no such function as `XMMatrixCompose`

Thanks,

Below is the document for this function
https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixdecompose

Answer (score 1):

[XMMatrixAffineTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixaffinetransformation) or [XMMatrixTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixtransformation). You pass a zero for the rotation origin value(s).

```
XMMATRIX mat = XMMatrixAffineTransformation(out_scale,
    g_XMZero,
    outRotQuat,
    out_trans);
```

> For more information on DirectXMath, see the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath/wiki).